# Uniform Convergence in Expectation of Diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Suppose that $X_t$ is a diffusion process on $\mathbb{R}$ and define the functionals $F_t$ from $L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathfrak{F}_t)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
F_t: Y\mapsto \mathbb{E}\left[
(X_{t} - Y)^2
\right],
$$
where $\mathfrak{F}_t$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_t$.

When does there exits $t_0>0$ for which $(F_t)_{t\in (0,t_0)}$ converge uniformly to $F_0$?

Comment: This question appears to be out of context. Could you add some more information?

Comment: What would help?  It's a diffusion, and if it helps it satisfies the uniform ellipticity condition.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to answer the question?

Comment: I have for a while, I was thinking of some sort of dominated convergence theorem argument but then I got stumped.